# Skype is not opening after entering the loging credentials in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, skype

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Today I tried to open the Skype, after providing the login credentials, automatically Skype got terminated.

One day before Skype was working properly.

Once I tried to open the Skype from the terminal, got the below error message:

> deepak@deepak:~$ skype  Gtk-Message: Failed to load module
>   "overlay-scrollbar" Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
>   Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge" Gtk-Message: Failed to
>   load module "unity-gtk-module"

Comment: sir i have a bunch of questions that can easily resumee into one, **how do you installed skype?** (explain detailed, if you don't remember delete this post(joke))

Comment: You can install from the ubuntu software center.

Comment: so you installed from the software center... that explains your problem

Comment: But it was working today morning and without installing any package or updating any package how it stopped working?

Comment: ask that to yourself, what did you do? what things ubuntu do... that you don't know while you work...

Comment: the errors that you putted here says that your system is unable to draw the windows and can't show you the skype client .. I'll guess that you rebooted your computer and then the skype stopped working... because you uninstalled something or your system updated something adn changed, not sure what... but something happened, and skype can't handle it, that's why I'm telling you to reinstall the whole thing

Comment: Once skype stopped working, from the terminal i just given update by using apt-get update.

Comment: But thank you after fresh installation skype starts working.

Comment: Micro$oft just updated Skype, adding some features <cough>bloat<cough>, so it's supposed to pop up a window telling you to upgrade to the newest version, but 9/10 it crashes (trial and error on my part). Nothing to do with gail and atk-bridge, imho, just bad coding on MS's part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't trust the *black magick* that makes the software center, in cases like this.
Remember, with linux things... the CLI is your best friend. :)

First you need to delete that buggy skype so open a terminal with <kbd>CTR</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
And type the following...
*Note: I'm assuming that your package is called `skype` since you copy-pasted that here*

```
sudo apt purge skype --auto-remove
```

Now go and download a fresh copy of Skype from the [oficial website](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/?type=weblinux-deb).
When you completed the download, go to the folder and right click 'open terminal'.
then you must type the following commands...
*Note: use <kbd>TAB</kbd> for autocompleting the annoying large name of the package*

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

With that done, your skype should work fine.
*If for some weird reason the installation gives you errors, then do 
`sudo apt update && dist-upgrade` for fixing missing libraries.*

Comment: Didn't help (((